# jquery event on change inline background color on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need a help detecting on change event of a background-color **inline** on "img" tag by a color picker.

For example, I have this code:

```
<span class="ui-button-text">
<img id="cp-background" src="transparent.png" style="background-color: rgb(100, 100, 90);"></img>
</span>
```

I need to detect if style="backgroung-color" as changed with Jquery.

I have tried this code, but I don't have sucess:

```
$("#ok-cp-background").data('bgcolor', $this.css('background-color')).change(function(){
     alert("Changed");
});
```

Can anyone please help me?

Thank You.

Comment: I think you need callback function, how do you change the background, please show us

Comment: Thank You for the reply. The backgroung-color in changed by a color picker... I "only" need a function that detect if style was changed.

Comment: I see if that is the case you should listen on the color pickers events. This should not only give you exactly when the color is chosen but also to what color.

Comment: what color picker? you made it yourself? or what? yes, AFAIK there is no way to fire something while attribute style was changed unless you need callback function. and `change()` event only work with `<input>,<textarea>, and <select>`.

Comment: Yes, I made my color picker. The image tag not is in the plugin, it is on page. I have two elements on page: this image tag and one hidden input. I need two know if the value was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simple solution is using the .trigger() function. Your script to attach event listener:

```
$("#cp-background").on("styleChanged",function(event, propertyName){

});
```

Extend your $.css() function to call trigger()

```
(function($)
{
    var oldcss = $.fn.css;
    $.fn.css = function()
    {
        var ret = oldcss.apply(this, arguments);
        if (arguments.length > 1){ //to ensure this function is called to assign a new style.
            this.trigger("styleChanged",arguments);
        }
        return ret;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Inside your color picker code, you use .css() to change the background-color.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. Unfortunately I could not get it working. I don't need to know the background color, just need to know when the plugin OK button was clicked. When this button is clicked, the image is altered as a background color. Is is possible add some event and then call it using javascript?

Comment: what do you mean? Can you make it clearer? From what I read:"I need to detect if style="backgroung-color" as changed with Jquery."

Comment: It is possible to execute this function one time? Not in cicling mode... For example, if the OK button is executed?

Comment: just change the $.on to $.one. Regards.

Comment: Thank You for all. I explained myself badly. What I want is that the event is executed whenever the user press the ok button and it can happen several times.